# xmpp client authorization jwt tokens

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

So Im trying to figure out how I can login to xmpp client with this jwt tokens.
I got no experience with xmpp so when I look online I only see code that login with user and pass.
Anybody can help me with this or lead me to some source on how to do this?

```
[OUT] 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stream:stream to="eu1.pvp.net" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"
    xmlns="jabber:client"
    xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
[IN] 
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <stream:stream
        xmlns='jabber:client'
        xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='3496705570' from='eu1.pvp.net' version='1.0'>
[IN] 
        <stream:features>
            <mechanisms
                xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
                <mechanism>X-Riot-RSO</mechanism>
                <mechanism>X-Riot-RSO-PAS</mechanism>
            </mechanisms>
        </stream:features>
[OUT] 
        <auth mechanism="X-Riot-RSO-PAS"
            xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
            <rso_token>ey...</rso_token>
            <pas_token>ey...</pas_token>
        </auth>
[IN] 
        <success
            xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>1628397936
        </success>
[OUT]
```

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: added code, do you know anything about xmpp?